# Find inverse of matrix with bezier coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, binomial-coefficients, bezier-curve

**Question:**

> Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a square matrix of side $(p+1)$, and coefficients
>
> $$A_{ij} = \binom{p}{j} \left(1-\dfrac{i}{p}\right)^{p-j} \left(\dfrac{i}{p}\right)^{j} \label{1}\tag{1}$$
>
> Is there an analitic expression for $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$?

**Motivation:**

> Let $B(u)$ be a bezier function of degree $p$ defined on $\left[0, \ 1\right]$.
>
> $$B(u) = \sum_{j=0}^{p} B_{j}(u) \cdot Q_{j} \label{2}\tag{2}$$
> $$B_{j}(u) = \binom{p}{j} \left(1-u\right)^{p-j} \cdot u^{j} \label{3}\tag{3}$$
>
> $B(u)$ interpolates $f(u)$ at equally distributed knots $u_{i} = \dfrac{i}{p}$
>
> $$B\left(\dfrac{i}{p}\right) = f\left(\dfrac{i}{p}\right) \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ i=0, \ \cdots, \ p \label{4}\tag{4}$$
>
> I need to find the control points $\mathbf{Q}$.
>
> > One way to find $\mathbf{Q}$ is by solving a linear system \eqref{6}.
> >
> > $$\sum_{j=0}^{p} B_{j}\left(u_i\right) \cdot Q_{j} = f\left(u_i\right) \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ i = 0, \ \cdots, \ p \label{5}\tag{5}$$
> > $$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
> > B_{0}(u_0) & B_{1}(u_0) & \cdots & B_{p}(u_0) \\
> > B_{0}(u_1) & B_{1}(u_1) & \cdots & B_{p}(u_1) \\
> > \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> > B_{0}(u_p) & B_{1}(u_p) & \cdots & B_{p}(u_p) \\
> > \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{A}}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
> > Q_0 \\ Q_1 \\ \vdots \\ Q_{p}
> > \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{Q}} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
> > f(u_0) \\ f(u_1) \\ \vdots \\ f(u_p)
> > \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{F}} \label{6}\tag{6}$$
> >
> > **Problem:** Solving the linear system using a computer is expensive.
>
> Then I search for a mathematical expression for $\mathbf{A}$'s inverse.
>
> $$\sum_{j=0}^{n} \underbrace{\binom{p}{j} \left(1-\dfrac{i}{p}\right)^{p-j} \left(\dfrac{i}{p}\right)^{j}}_{A_{ij}} \cdot Q_{j} = f\left(u_i\right)\ \ \ \ \ \forall i=0, \cdots, p \label{7}\tag{7}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix you’re dealing with is called a Bernstein-Vandermonde matrix. For an analytic expression for its inverse, look at section 2.3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.03251.pdf), or [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327002836_A_note_on_Bernstein-Vandermonde_matrices).

But the inversion formulas are very complex, and I’m not sure they’re worth the effort. If you’re really concerned about performance, I’d recommend just hard-coding the matrix inverses. For each degree that interests you, compute the matrix inverse once, in exact arithmetic (by using Mathematica, for example), and store it in your code.

I don’t know how you’re going to use this interpolation function. But if you’re trying to approximate $f$ using a Bézier curve, then using equally spaced points $i/p$ is a really bad idea. Use Chebyshev nodes, instead. You’ll get a different family of Bernstein-Vandermonde matrices, but you can still pre-compute their inverses.